# Store first non-missing value in a new column

Tags: r, extract, apply

Ciao, I have several columns that represents scores. For each STUDENT I want to take the first non-NA score and store it in a new column called TEST.

Here is my replicating example. This is the data I have now:

```
df <- data.frame(STUDENT=c(1,2,3,4,5), 
                 CLASS=c(90,91,92,93,95),
                 SCORE1=c(10,NA,NA,NA,NA), 
                 SCORE2=c(2,NA,8,NA,NA), 
                 SCORE3=c(9,6,6,NA,NA),
                 SCORE4=c(NA,7,5,1,9),
                 ROOM=c(01,02, 03, 04, 05))
```

This is the column I am aiming to add:

```
df$FIRST <- c(10,6,8,1,9)
```

This is my attempt:

```
df$FIRSTGUESS <- max.col(!is.na(df[3:6]), "first")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly what `coalesce` from package `dplyr` does. As described in its documentation:

> Given a set of vectors, coalesce() finds the first non-missing value
>   at each position.

Therefore, you can simplify do:

```
library(dplyr)
df$FIRST <- do.call(coalesce, df[grepl('SCORE', names(df))])
```

This is the result:

```
> df
  STUDENT CLASS SCORE1 SCORE2 SCORE3 SCORE4 ROOM FIRST
1       1    90     10      2      9     NA    1    10
2       2    91     NA     NA      6      7    2     6
3       3    92     NA      8      6      5    3     8
4       4    93     NA     NA     NA      1    4     1
5       5    95     NA     NA     NA      9    5     9
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `apply` and `which.min(is.na(...))`

```
df$FIRSTGUESS <- apply(df[, grep("^SCORE", names(df))], 1, function(x) 
    x[which.min(is.na(x))])
df
#  STUDENT CLASS SCORE1 SCORE2 SCORE3 SCORE4 ROOM FIRSTGUESS
#1       1    90     10      2      9     NA    1         10
#2       2    91     NA     NA      6      7    2          6
#3       3    92     NA      8      6      5    3          8
#4       4    93     NA     NA     NA      1    4          1
#5       5    95     NA     NA     NA      9    5          9
```

Note that we need `is.na` instead of `!is.na` because `FALSE` corresponds to `0` and we want to return the first (`which.min`) `FALSE` value.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, `max.col` gives indices of max values and not the values itself. However, we can subset the values from the original dataframe using the `mapply` call.

```
#Select only columns which has "SCORE" in it
sub_df <- df[grepl("SCORE", names(df))]

#Get the first non-NA value by row 
inds <- max.col(!is.na(sub_df), ties.method = "first")

#Get the inds value by row
df$FIRSTGUESS <- mapply(function(x, y) sub_df[x,y], 1:nrow(sub_df), inds)

df

#  STUDENT CLASS SCORE1 SCORE2 SCORE3 SCORE4 ROOM FIRST FIRSTGUESS
#1       1    90     10      2      9     NA    1    10         10
#2       2    91     NA     NA      6      7    2     6          6
#3       3    92     NA      8      6      5    3     8          8
#4       4    93     NA     NA     NA      1    4     1          1
#5       5    95     NA     NA     NA      9    5     9          9
```

Comment: Just borrowing your setting up :-)

Answer (score 0):

Using `zoo`,`na.locf`, borrowing the setting up of `sub_df` from [Ronak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52305456/7964527)

```
 df['New']=zoo::na.locf(t(sub_df),fromLast=T)[1,]
 df
  STUDENT CLASS SCORE1 SCORE2 SCORE3 SCORE4 ROOM New
1       1    90     10      2      9     NA    1  10
2       2    91     NA     NA      6      7    2   6
3       3    92     NA      8      6      5    3   8
4       4    93     NA     NA     NA      1    4   1
5       5    95     NA     NA     NA      9    5   9
```